# Observer design pattern multithreading communication

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, observer-pattern

the below question is kind of an abstract question, and i would be grateful to listen to opinions about the problem.

My problem is the below:

I have a Thread listening to data feeds and storing those to a cache. Every time something is added on the cache an observer picks it up and adds it to a HashMap. I dont know before-hand how many feeds i will get, but the number is not infinite.

Additionally, my application runs another thread which is doing some processing and then retrieves the values inside the HashMap.

My problem here is that i do not really know if all the values have been stored in the HashMap, so i cannot relly synchronize the two threads between them or notify the later thread that the job of storing all the feeds has been finished.

The flow looks similar to the below:

```
Thread-1 -> listens for data feeds -> cache data feeds -> cache observer -> HashMap

                                                                               ^
                                                                               |
Thread-2 -> starting execution at a random time and needs data from the      HashMap
```

I would be really interested in listening to some suggestions to that problem. The only tricky thing to consider in the above is that i do not really know the number of feeds to be stored in the HashMap, thus i cannot really wait to be notified by the other thread that is responsible for storing the objects.

Any response appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a queue instead of a hash map? In case of a queue you can put in a marker element that signifies the end of the data feed.

Comment: If this is Java, `HashMap` isn't thread-safe so make sure you wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedMap` or use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: @artbristol Nice suggestion. It is actually a ConcurrentHashMap. The actual problem is not incocistency of data, but i am not notified that the operation of copying data feeds has finished.

Comment: @ShyamalPandya This sounds rather interesting. Will try that to see if it fits my purposes and post back my results. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand completely the event model. When you start Thread-2 during operation of Thread-1, and finish BEFORE Thread-1, is Thread-2 supposed to wait for the rest of feeds (until it finds the theoretical marker)? What is expected to happen when there is a marker already, Thread-2 starts eating feeds and suddenly Thread-1 removes the marker and starts adding new feeds? I have a nagging feeling that the whole model is somehow wrong.

Comment: Does your requirement to "know the number of feeds to be stored" mean, that Thread-2 processing only works on "blocks" of stored feeds? That it doesn't make sense to start on "some feeds" already present in the map?

Comment: @PavelZdenek Thanks for the reply. You are right when you say there is something wrong with the model. Unfortunately i cannot change it, thus i was trying to find a solution first. The actual case is that Thread-1 shouldnt take too long to retrieve all feeds and store them in the HashMap (the feeds are usually about 100). But Thread-2 is not notified whether all the feeds are stored in the HashMap. One more problem is that Thread-1 will only look once at the HashMap and then continue with the data that were already there. I can make THread-2 to sleep for a while but i dont like that solution.

Comment: @PavelZdenek I think the best solution would be to know the number of feeds to be stored and make Thread-2 wait() until Thread-1 notifies it to proceed. But it is impossible for me to know the number of feeds. Thus i reckon the only solution to proceed is to make Thread-2 sleep for a sufficient period of time and then read the HashMap. I am thinking of adding some logic, after that, if the operation fails to re-read the HashMap one more time just in case it missed some records. I can already see too many flaws in that though.

Comment: "*One more problem is that Thread-1 will only look once at the HashMap*" you wanted to say *Thread-2* right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21332/discussion-between-pavel-zdenek-and-nikkatsa)

Comment: @PavelZdenek yes indeed. That was a typo. Thread-2 i was meant to write. Sorry but the stackoverflow's chat is blocked by company's firewall.

Comment: Ok copy: Though, i still don't understand why you need "all the values" and/or "know the number of feeds". Can't it be a simple producer/consumer, which means that Thread-1 simply keeps putting feeds into the map and Thread-2 keeps reading whatever is there (if anything) ? Do you need to maintain some kind of feed blocks? Do the feed make sense only in groups? Also, why do you need Map? How do you check in Thread-2 how many feeds has been added? Map is not very suitable for it.

Comment: @PavelZdenek The above situation is happening in an integration test for a particular scenario. Thus, i cannot really wait and keep listening to changes in the Map. I have pre-recorded data, which are the feeds, and after they are added in the cache (and subsequently) to the Map, i am reading the feeds, do my calculations and compare with the expected result. Because this is a one off execution, the test cannot really wait and listen to the Map for changes. The test passes intermitently, when the publisher is fast enough to publish feeds from the cache to the HashMap.

Comment: @PavelZdenek I know that i can just read all the feeds from the cache from Thread-2 in my program. But this would actually break the use case scenario that is taking place in reality, so the integration test would not be useful. I am thinking, because is actually a CI test to put a sufficient sleep in Thread-2 (about 10 secs) so the test will pass (hopefuly) all the times. Thanks for your suggestions and the time spent.

Comment: Can't you use a Condition to wake up Thread-2 directly from Thread-1 upon finishing the prerecorded test data? Can the two threads in test share a Condition object (via dependency injection perhaps) ?

Comment: @PavelZdenek Thanks for the suggestions. Actually this is the solution i followed. I had a class which was the one responsible for publishing the feeds and then the feeds where ending in the HashMap. This class had BlockingQueues and ThreadPoolExecutors. So with Spring, i injected that class into the class that requests the HashMap's values. I added a method waitUntilIdle(), which method checks if the BlockingQueues are empty and then it terminates the ThreadPoolExecutors. This solves it. Thank you for the usefull help.

Comment: I have made an answer from my last post, which you named useful. Accept it as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use a `Condition` to wake up `Thread-2` directly from `Thread-1` upon finishing the prerecorded test data? Can the two threads in test share a `Condition` object (via dependency injection perhaps) ?